# Question about a Dragonfire Adept build

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization

For part of a Dragonfire Adept build idea, I was considering using either Silverbrow Human or Dragon Descended, but then I had another idea: why not both? Would it be possible to combine those two racial traits, and if so, would it be worthwile to do so?

Also, would it be redundant for a Dragonfire Adept to take the Draconic Wings feat, or would it be potentially beneficial?

Comment: "Dragon Descended"? Where's that from? New one on me. The primary benefit of Silverbrow Human (the Dragonblooded subtype) is wasted on Dragonfire Adepts since they get that as a class feature.

Comment: Dragon Descended is from Races of the Dragon; it grants Darkvision 60ft, low-light vision, a +4 racial bonus saves against sleep and paralysis effects, a +2 bonus to STR, CON, and CHA, and a +2 racial bonus on Intimidate and Spot checks all for a +1 level modifier to the base race.

Comment: Ah, I think you mean the Draconic template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Draconic Flight*** is clearly better.

*Dragon Wings* vs *Draconic Flight*:

- 2 feats vs 1 lesser invocation (1 feat at most)
- Fixed 30ft average maneuverability vs land speed good maneuverability
- Doesn't allow overland flight until 12HD vs at will casting, 24h duration, bonuses to checks on a forced march.

***Draconic creature*** is acceptable, if your DM allows [LA-buyoff](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/races/reducingLevelAdjustments.htm).

Otherwise it is sub-par, but not prohibitively so.
As for *silverbrow human* - you don't need *dragonblood* subtype since you get it from *dragonfire adept*, so it is essentially bonus skill points traded for feather fall and +2 to disguise.

IMO not worth it except for fluff reasons, and if combined with *draconic creature* not worth it at all, its fluff rendered redundant by template.

Comment: It's fluff is largely rendered redundant by Dragonfire Adept, considering that you are considered Dragonblooded as a result of the class and are therefore apparently also descended from dragons.

Comment: So Dragonic Flight does everything Dragon Wings does and better; got it. Also, the Draconic Creature template as I described it was presented as PC-viable in the book Races of the Dragon, so I don't think my DM would have any problems with me using it.